# using the django rest framework properly

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here is one of the functions I have using the django rest framework:

```
elif request.method == 'POST':
    text = request.POST.get('text')
    request_to_meet = request.POST.get('request')
    startup = request.POST.get('startup')
    to_user_id = request.POST.get('tid')

    try:
        to_user = User.objects.get(pk=to_user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        to_user = None

    if 'conversation_id' in request.POST:
        conversation_id = request.POST.get('conversation_id')
    else:
        conversation_id = 0

    ct = Chat.objects.create(
        from_user=user,
        to_user=to_user,
        text=text,
        startup=startup,
        request=request_to_meet,
        conversation_id=conversation_id)

    serializer = ChatSerializer(ct, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Am I using the framework properly? I had to use the create( model function in django instead of using the serializer save function. Is that the proper way to right api code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me preface by saying, I am new to django rest framework too.

The main things I see are:

1. Are you using [`api_view`](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers.html) decorator, which provides the free web based documentation of your api methods
2. Using `request.DATA` will automatically map requests with `JSON` in the body and content type `application/json` to variables.

I have yet to use serializers to create data instances also, but doing so should automatically return appropriate errors based on incorrect datatypes/missing fields, etc, opposed to you having to manually handle all your validation and object creation yourself.